# Extracting text from chart in Beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Relatively new to beautifulsoup and I'm trying to extract data from this webpage: http://reports.workforce.test.ohio.gov/program-county-wia-reports.aspx?name=GTL8gAmmdulY5GSlycy7WQ==&dataType=hIp9ibmBIwbKor1WvT5Bkg==&dataTypeText=hIp9ibmBIwbKor1WvT5Bkg==#

I would like to grab the numbers under the headings "Program Completers", "Employed Second Quarter", etc. A relevant part of the html code is:

```
<ul class="listbox">              
 <li class="li1">
  <p style="cursor:help" class="listtop" title="WIA Adult 
  completers are those individuals who have exited a WIA Adult program from 
  which the individual received a core staff-assisted service (such as job 
  search or placement assistance) or an intensive service (such as
  counseling, career planning, or job training). Those individuals who 
  participated in WIA through self-service, like OhioMeansJobs.com, or other 
  less intensive programs are not included in the dashboard.">Program 
  Completers</p>
  <p id="programcompleters1">18</p></li>
```

I want the string "Program Completers" and "18". I have tried implementing these solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172644/extract-attribute-value-in-beautiful-soup), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27327998/why-is-this-tag-empty-when-parsed-with-beautiful-soup), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23380171/using-beautifulsoup-extract-text-without-tags) but without much luck. One version of my code is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url="http://reports.workforce.test.ohio.gov/program-county-wia-reports.aspx?name=GTL8gAmmdulY5GSlycy7WQ==&dataType=hIp9ibmBIwbKor1WvT5Bkg==&dataTypeText=hIp9ibmBIwbKor1WvT5Bkg=="
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36',
       'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'}

req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=hdr)
page = urllib2.urlopen(req)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
for tag in soup.find_all('ul'):
    print tag.text, tag.next_sibling
```

This returns text but from other parts of the webpage also tagged 'ul'. I have been unsuccessful in grabbing any text from inside the chart area. How can I retrieve the text I want?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Thank you! Both answers worked, but @Matt_Davidson's solution gets me the more specific data I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned before the data you're looking for is in an iframe, access it as @chosen_codex says here:

http://reports.workforce.test.ohio.gov/WIAReports/WIA_COUNTY.ASPX?level=county&DataType=hIp9ibmBIwbKor1WvT5Bkg==&name=GTL8gAmmdulY5GSlycy7WQ==&programDate=Kf/2jvCFFRgQJjODWV7l08ATxxM/adw9p1FWfZ9J7O8=

You can then access the fields you are interested by:

```
data = {}
for tag in soup.find_all('p'):
    if tag.get('id'):
        data[tag.get('id')] = tag.text

print(data)

>> print(data.get('programcompleters1'))
18
```

Answer (score 0):

The elements you want are inside an iframe. Try extracting from the page itself at http://reports.workforce.test.ohio.gov/WIAReports/WIA_COUNTY.ASPX?level=county&DataType=hIp9ibmBIwbKor1WvT5Bkg==&name=GTL8gAmmdulY5GSlycy7WQ==&programDate=Kf/2jvCFFRgQJjODWV7l08ATxxM/adw9p1FWfZ9J7O8=

so, this should work

```
url="http://reports.workforce.test.ohio.gov/WIAReports/WIA_COUNTY.ASPX?level=county&DataType=hIp9ibmBIwbKor1WvT5Bkg==&name=GTL8gAmmdulY5GSlycy7WQ==&programDate=Kf/2jvCFFRgQJjODWV7l08ATxxM/adw9p1FWfZ9J7O8="
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

chartcontainers = soup.findAll('div', {"class": "chartcontain"})
for container in chartcontainers:
    print(container)
    #then do whatever
```